# update page in PHP in a specific time

Tags: php

Hi I have the following code which can send text messages according to the date of birth and hour but the page has to be updated  manually i would like it to update at a specific time, for example every day at 06:00 am. There a way in PHP?

```
$deviceID = 12345;
$number = $resultado;
$message = 'Happy Birthday man!!';
$options = [
'send_at' => strtotime(date('Y-'.$birth_dates.' 09:42:00',time())),
'expires_at' => strtotime('+1 hour') // Cancel the message in 1 hour if the  message is not yet sent
];
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message,  $deviceID,$options);
?>
```

Comment: This is not possible by means of php, since the server side cannot actively contact the client side. You can do that using client side logic (javascript).

Comment: An example in javascript? please

Comment: Take a look at javascripts `setTimeout()` function. You will find tons of examples on the internet.

Comment: You should use a cronjob to activate your php script

Comment: Thanks I'll looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a cronjob, not a page. You can set when the task will be executed, so your sms will be sent.